# CakePHP 2.1.1 foreach

Tags: cakephp-2.1

In my view I want a HTML table something like this:

```
     COUNTRY         TOWN
      france         paris
```

This is my query:

```
$foo=$this->country->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
            'Town' => array(
                'conditions' => array("Town.country_id = country.id"),
                'fields' => array('id','name')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I want to display to my view like this:

```
 line6        <?php foreach ($diponibilite as $f): ?>
 line7  
 line8            <tr>
 line9                <td><?php echo $f['country']['name'];?></td>
 line10             <td><?php echo $f['town']['name'];?></td>
 line11         
 line12            </tr>
 line13        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The models 'country' and 'town' are associated:

```
country hasmany town and town belongsto country
```

unfortunately, an error:

> Notice (8): Undefined index: name [APP\View\index\index.ctp, line 10]

Why?

Comment: Let's start with basic debugging. Add `debug( $f );` to the view inside the loop. Does it have the `name` key?

Comment: hi Juhana! thanks for your comment. i done your suggest: adding debug($f) to the view inside the loop and this is the contents:                                                              'array(
 'country' => array(
  'id' => '1',
  'name' => 'france'
 ),
 'town' => array(
  (int) 0 => array(
   'id' => '1',
   'name' => 'paris',
   'country_id' => '1'
  ),
  (int) 1 => array(
   'id' => '2',
   'name' => 'marseille',
   'country_id' => '1'
  )
 )
)'         i get the same error. i think i dont use the correct syntax to find value in an array with the foreach() statement???? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that since you have a `Country hasmany Town` relationship there could be multiple towns in one country (as the output of `debug( $f )` shows).

To print all of the towns you need another loop:

```
<?php foreach( $diponibilite as $f ): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $f[ 'country' ][ 'name' ]; ?></td>
        <td><?php 
            foreach( $f[ 'town' ] as $town ) {
                echo $town[ 'name' ].' ';
            }
        ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Or, if you just want the first one, use `$f[ 'town' ][ 0 ][ 'name' ]`.

Side note: if you have the associations set up properly, you don't need the condition in the find. You can just do

```
$foo = $this->country->find( 'all', array(
    'contain' => array(
            'Town.id',
            'Town.name'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Greats thanks Juhana! following your suggest, my error disappear! this is my code:      <br/>    `<table>`
`<tr> <td>country</td>  <td>town</td>    </tr>`
`<?php foreach( $diponibilite as $f ): ?>`
`    <?php foreach( $f[ 'town' ] as $town ):?>`
`    <tr>`
`        <td><?php echo $f[ 'country' ][ 'name' ]; ?></td>`
`        <td><?php echo $town[ 'name' ];?></td>`
`    </tr>`
`<?php endforeach; ?>`
`<?php endforeach; ?>`
`</table>`

and the view display something like this:

     country           town
    france            paris
    france            marseille

once again thanks Juhana!