# CakePHP- Iterate Array

Tags: cakephp, multidimensional-array

How can I Iterate over this ridiculously tedious array?

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Question' => 
        array (size=2)
          'id' => string 'q_1' (length=3)
          'question_desc' => string 'Is this correct?)' (length=15)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Question' => 
        array (size=2)
          'id' => string 'q_10' (length=4)
          'question_desc' => string 'Do you weigh less than 45 kilograms OR more than 160 kilograms.' (length=63)
```

This is a var_dump from a Session data!  I need to get the `question_desc` field from each `'Question'` array object.

Comment: As I can see here is case with array of arrays here is sample http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp   also if you know how to iterate over one array just need after first iteration start iteration of child array.

Comment: here is sample http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342755/cakephp-2-1-1-foreach

Comment: Sorry I might have not been clear... Is there a cake PHP way for doing it.. Iteration such as Foreach is pretty simply

Comment: Ahaam  , as  I know there is not anything special in CakePHP according  foreach loop.

Comment: Oh ok so im stuck with iterations. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This array has a purpose to its structure, but I understand your frustration as I shared it before I rtfm-ed!

```
$flattened_data = array();

foreach($your_main_array as $question)
{
    foreach($question['Question'] as $question_param)
    {
        if($question_param == 'question_desc')
        {
            $flattened_data[] = $question_param;

            // if you want to be really cool you can do this instead
            // this will list the array with the question id as the key.
            //  $flattened_data[$question[id]] = $question_param;           
        }
    }
}

// now flattened data has only what you require
return $flattened_data;
```

Cakes data form makes a lot more sense once you understand its ORM and how it uses model relations. Its actually a powerful tool for managing your data, but before you need all of that power it does seem like an encumbrance for simple tasks.

Comment: Actuall this returns an empty array for some reason! oh and thanks for sharing my frustration. I literally felt like crap being confused between iterations.

Comment: You did switch `$your_main_array` to the actual name of your array right?

Comment: yes ofcourse! Why areyou checking if  $question_param == 'question_desc' ? it seems that the condition is never met

Comment: Also I've just read about `Set::flatten` in a completely different post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942716/cakephp-element-to-display-validation-errors